# kubernetes airflow hive operator error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hive';

Tags: python, kubernetes, hive, airflow

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to run a HiveOperator task in Apache Airflow with the Kubernetes Executor.

I have a Dockerfile where I installed the necessary dependencies including apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive==6.4.1:

Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.8.2
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r /requirements.txt
RUN umask 0002; \
    mkdir -p /tmp
```

And in my Airflow task, I have defined a HiveOperator as follows:

```py
hive_select = HiveOperator(
        task_id='hive_select',
        hive_cli_conn_id='hive_conn',
        hql="select * from table LIMIT 10",
        execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=30)
    )
```

However, when I attempt to execute this task, I encounter the following error:

```
[2024-02-29, 09:05:15 UTC] {hive.py:275} INFO - hive -hiveconf airflow.ctx.dag_id=hive_con_test -hiveconf airflow.ctx.task_id=hive_select -hiveconf airflow.ctx.execution_date=2024-02-29T09:02:14.534414+00:00 -hiveconf airflow.ctx.try_number=4 -hiveconf airflow.ctx.dag_run_id=manual__2024-02-29T09:02:14.534414+00:00 -hiveconf airflow.ctx.dag_owner=airflow -hiveconf airflow.ctx.dag_email= -hiveconf mapred.job.name=Airflow HiveOperator task for hive-con-test-hive-select-g7oo5n2s.hive_con_test.hive_select.2024-02-29T09:02:14.534414+00:00 -f /tmp/airflow_hiveop_wg4va81k/tmpwyi3r0ow
[2024-02-29, 09:05:15 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2728} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 439, in _execute_task
    result = _execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 414, in _execute_callable
    return execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/operators/hive.py", line 172, in execute
    self.hook.run_cli(hql=self.hql, schema=self.schema, hive_conf=self.hiveconfs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/hooks/hive.py", line 276, in run_cli
    sub_process: Any = subprocess.Popen(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1953, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hive'
[2024-02-29, 09:05:15 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1149} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=hive_con_test, task_id=hive_select, execution_date=20240229T090214, start_date=20240229T090514, end_date=20240229T090515
[2024-02-29, 09:05:15 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 214 for task hive_select ([Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hive'; 28)
[2024-02-29, 09:05:15 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:234} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2024-02-29, 09:05:15 UTC] {taskinstance.py:3309} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hive'`

It seems like there's a permission issue related to executing the Hive CLI. I tried setting permissions on the /tmp/ folder as suggested in some resources, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Any insights on how to resolve this permission issue and successfully run the HiveOperator task would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ROM apache/airflow:2.8.2
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r /requirements.txt
RUN umask 0002; 
mkdir -p /tmp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).